# problem with parameters of the query

Tags: c#

I'm having troubles passing parameters to a query throws this exception

**The parameterized query '(@IdIndicador int)INSERT INTO [AtentoMIG].[dbo].[Indicador]([Nom' expects the parameter '@IdIndicador', which was not supplied.**

**this is my code**

```
_sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
              ("INSERT INTO [AtentoMIG].[dbo].[Indicator]"                      
                  + "([Name]"
                  + ",[Descripction])"
                  + "VALUES"
                  + "('" + data[0] + "'"
                  + ",'" + data[13] + "') SET @IdIndicador = SCOPE_IDENTITY()", _sqlConexion);

SqlParameter idIndicador = new SqlParameter("@IdIndicador", SqlDbType.Int);
_sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(idIndicador);
_sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
_sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
int id = (int)idIndicador.Value;

_sqlConexion.Close();
return true;
```

Why am i doing wrong?? for me the code looks good

Comment: Besides your error the SQL Injection issues.

Comment: @Joe that's nothing to do with my question, besides, it's just a test. i know that could inject code

Comment: well thats good that you know and there was no way of anyone else knowing that it is just test code. Just bringing it to your attention and the purpose of saying "Besides your error" refers to the fact I know it is unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You forgot to supply the direction of the `SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction.aspx). Try adding:

```
SqlParameter idIndicador = new SqlParameter("@IdIndicador", SqlDbType.Int);
idIndicator.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
// ...
```